unable to mount a folder on N drive from windows to docker via compose
in my docker-compose.yaml I have tried everything including this current version:
volumes:
  - "/N/gpt/llama/llama3-main/Meta-Llama-3-8B/:/data/Meta-Llama-3-8B/"
  - "/N/gpt/simple-api/:/app/"

I've tried with/without ending /
with/without N:
with/without \ double backslash instead of forward
etc.etc.etc.
However, when I run the container with docker-compose run --rm --service-ports api /usr/bin/bash
both /app and /data/Meta-Llama-3-8B are both empty
I noticed that some others posted that within settings/resources/fileshare is an option to allow drive sharing.  Two things:
In my case N is a network share, although it's wide open
Second, in settings/resources I don't have an option for fileshare, just:
Advanced, Proxies, Network and WSL Integration
Any ideas/suggestions?
I actually tried moving the folder to my C drive, and it works fine, but I'd really like it to work from the N drive.
